# Login isn't performed in sping security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I try to implement login in my spring app. In sample project it works perfect, but in work project it works partially. In my work project after login becomes available access to private pages, but next code don't perfomes correctly in html page:

```
<div sec:authentication="name"></div>
<sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()">
    You can <a href="/login">login</a> or <a href="/registration">register</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

It always writes "You can login or register" and don't writes username.
Database's the same the both cases.

Just in case I write my config files
WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/registration").not().fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/news").hasAuthority("USER")
                .antMatchers("/", "/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

MvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/news").setViewName("news");
    }
}
```

UserService.java:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return user;
    }

    public User findUserById(Long userId) {
        Optional<User> userFromDb = userRepository.findById(userId);
        return userFromDb.orElse(new User());
    }

    public List<User> allUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public boolean saveUser(User user) {
        User userFromDB = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if (userFromDB != null) {
            return false;
        }

        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new Role(1L, "ROLE_USER")));
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean deleteUser(Long userId) {
        if (userRepository.findById(userId).isPresent()) {
            userRepository.deleteById(userId);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public List<User> usergtList(Long idMin) {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id > :paramId", User.class)
                .setParameter("paramId", idMin).getResultList();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.momentum</groupId>
    <artifactId>finstrument</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>finstrument</name>
    <description>Finstrument</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>42.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rosuda.REngine</groupId>
            <artifactId>Rserve</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: How does look your `UserService` and pom dependencies for security?

Comment: @nazar_art, I've added them

Comment: You are using Thymeleaf there is no `sec:` tag you need to add that to a div (or the code here isn't the actual code you are using).

Comment: @M.Deinum, this is spring security dialect. https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html
I added it in html tag:
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"

Comment: I know, but it has to be on an container, you cannot use it as an element so `<sec: ...` won't work you need something like `<span sec:...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And I've changed html-thymeleaf code:

```
<div sec:authentication="name"></div>
<span sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    You can <a href="/login">login</a> or <a href="/registration">register</a> to add your company!
</span>
```